# Which one will give me the best VPN security when choosing Encryption algorithm in pfsense?

Tags: vpn, aes

I want to setup an VPN server in pfsense and I can choose a lot of Encryption algorithm types ,alot!!
What I have read is that the AES 256 (512 is not an option) is the best. Well even then there are a couple of option this is what I can choose from:

1. CBC
2. CFB
3. CFB1
4. CFB8
5. OFB

I did find this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220751/how-to-choose-an-aes-encryption-mode-cbc-ecb-ctr-ocb-cfb, but it did not include all options and there are some critic comments on the answer. Of course there is an wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation , but that does not give me an clear answer on what is the most secure and gives a lot of extra info I do not understand.

**Question 1: Is AES 256 the most  secure algorithm?**

**Question 2: If 1 is true then which one of the above list is the most secure?**

Many thanks and any thought about this is appreciated!!

Comment: pfSense provides even more VPN encryption options than the ones you listed https://cl.ly/1o331r0a2u1y/Screenshot%202016-09-08%2020.29.05.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. AES-256 is the most secure publicly known algorithm. It is however probable, that there exist more secure algorithms in the military use.
2. From the above list, OFB will be the most secure and also the least CPU intensive.

Here you have some explanation about these modes:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation

Comment: Many thanks, but have things like Encryption parallelizable no inpact on the security (because OFB do not have that option)?

Comment: I didn't mention paralellizable encryption. In fact, either CBC and OFB can be more secure than the other, depending on what you use it for. For VPN and its traffic encryption character, OFB should be better than CBC. Detailed explanation would require mathematical proof, and I don't unfortunately have time for that in work, so I provided you Wikipedia link, where you can read about each mode and try to understand the differences.

Comment: Of course, that is true. I don't even  think that I have the knowledge to understand the mathematical explanation, but many thanks anyway.

Comment: AES-256 is __not__ the most secure publicly known algorithm, however it is still practically unbreakable. Newer CPUs have hardware acceleration so it is very fast and very secure.
Also, how is OFB the least CPU intensive from the list? For example a [benchmark](http://www.cryptopp.com/benchmarks.html) says OFB is slightly slower than CBC.

Comment: @KovBal would you mind disclosing what you believe is the most secure publicly known algorithm?